# Why Service Hook doesn't triggers deployment on opsworks stack?

Tags: github, webhooks, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to trigger deployment on my opsworks stack every time there is a push to an specific branch(GitHub), I followed the instructions here http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2014-01-22-github-service-hook-for-aws-ops-works.html and entered the stack id, app id, branch name and Aws Access key.

The problem is that when I push to my branch the service hook doesn't trigger the deployment on opsworks, I also tried using the "Test Service" button in my service hook on Github but it only says:

```
"Okay, the test payload is on its way."
```

but there is no response back, I also look at my permissions level as suggested in this post [Can I automate an application deployment via webhook to OpsWorks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191467/can-i-automate-an-application-deployment-via-webhook-to-opsworks) and everything looks good.

From documentation here https://developer.github.com/webhooks/testing/ says "Every webhook has its own "Recent Deliveries" section" which I can't find for "Integrations & services", so there is no way to check what happened.

Is there a way in GitHub to see the log or history of my service hook?, or how do I check the response?

Comment: Not sure why I got negative point on this one, it will be nice to know the reason will help to improve my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, its bug on GitHub congifuration providers and was reported 4 hours ago: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11824

Basically they are hard-coding the API endpoint to us-east-1 which will only work if your VPC is in that region, I run a few tests with an stack where the api endpoint was us-east-1 and it worked.

To make this work you will have to create another VPC that lives under the same region or wait to see when this will get resolved by GitHub.

**UPDATED:**

Here is a link to the source code used by the service https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/master/lib/services/aws_ops_works.rb

Comment: Thanks - I'm having the same problem and this confirmed my suspicion. Hopefully GitHub will sort soon; unfortunately the issue you linked isn't for Github's service implementation, so I'm not sure if it's being fixed or not.

Comment: I've submitted a PR to add a config option for the API endpoint - https://github.com/github/github-services/pull/1206

Comment: thanks!! I submitted a bug with github and they didn't acknowledged as a bug the reply was "we're currently accepting only bug fixes and security improvements for those services, With that in mind, I don't think more configuration options will be added in the near future. So I'd recommend using a plain webhook instead, pointing it at a small proxy service you'd build, and then use that proxy service for calling opsworks." :(

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation `webhooks/testing`](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/testing/) says "Every webhook has its own "Recent Deliveries" section", which I can't find for "Integrations & services", so there is no way to check what happened.

[Update June 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-30-webhook-deliveries-api/), there is now, through GitHub API

> You can now programmatically check the status and resend repository, organization, and Apps webhooks through the REST API, to complement functionality currently provided in the [Settings user interface](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/testing-webhooks#listing-recent-deliveries).
>
> Using [these new API endpoints](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#webhooks), you can now list webhook delivery attempts from the last 30 days, read the status and payload of specific deliveries, and trigger a redelivery if needed.